# What products and materials dissolve in water? - Marketing Course

Tags: recycling

I'm currently working on a design project in my marketing class requiring me to create a prototype that helps with an everyday issue. I'm curious to find a material that only dissolves in water. It cannot dissolve in other liquids, as it will be used for recycling and regular garbage.

Comment: Supposing there was such a substance, what would make water so unique that there were a substance that only it could dissolve?

Comment: chemistry question, not really an engineering question

Comment: This is actually a really complicated topic requiring knowledge of how materials actually break bonds to be soluble in a liquid (which is beyond what most engineers learn in Chem 1 & 2).  "Only water" is also a bit vague.  Does it include acids and bases which are water-based?  I suggest that if you must create a working prototype you stick to things that don't require advanced chemistry knowledge.

Comment: This requirement may be impossible, if taken literally

Comment: If it dissolves in water it very likely dissolves in any highly polar liquid.